# Java: ArrayList for storing doubles

Tags: java, arraylist, double

A very basic question but I am having a little bit of trouble, I am very new to Java (my only experience prior is VB.NET which I developed on for a couple of years but never really used any OOP principles)

I need an array implementation for a load of decimal numbers. I'm not sure how many I'll have so I need an array which can dynamically change it's size and I've been told an ArrayList is the way to go.

So I've tried this:

```
ArrayList<double> xCo = new ArrayList<double>();
```

And my compiler gets angry and asks me for a "reference" in space of where double goes. I'm certain I'm misunderstanding something the whole declaration process of these things so how am I supposed to go about doing it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to your first taste of Java generics hell. We'll have you wishing you were back in .NET with C# in no time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use primitives in generics, use `Double` instead. Note the capitalization.

Comment: The docs are below....note that you will now have members available to you since its a list of objects not primitives http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Comment: haha.  sorry about that  didn't notice :)  ...though i doubt it changed much

Comment: I'm on 1.5 anyway :) The problem is now sorted, thanks to everyone for their assistance. Although I now have another issue which is just getting used to the whole Arraylist thing anyway, oh well that'll come in time

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use java primitives in Generics , instead you have to use [java primitive wrapper types](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Wrapperclassesfortheprimitivetypes.htm)

Change it to

```
ArrayList<Double> xCo = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Check this tutorial to learn more on Generics

- [Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 1):

use Double instead of double ,hoping you have imported java.util.Arraylist package

Answer (score 0):

You want `Double`, not `double`:

```
ArrayList<Double> xCo = new ArrayList<Double>();
```